# Kendo UI Grid MVC - Batch inline editing - Datepicker not displayed for DateTime field

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using the MVC Kendo Grid with 4 columns, one of them is a DateTime field.
The grid allows inline and batch editing. When I click on a Boolean field, it shows a checkbox. If I click on a text field, it displays a TextField. I would guess that for a date field, it should show a DatePicker. 
Instead it shows a TextField.

Here is the column declaration on the grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyModel>()
            .Name("Grid")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
columns.Bound(e => e.MyDate).Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy}").Title("Date");
})
.Editable(x => x.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
.Batch(true)
```

Here is my model property:

```
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)] // making data type as date     
public DateTime? MyDate{ get; set; }
```

What am I missing? My only guess at this point is a missing .js file or something? Please let me know.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add editor templates for same. You can get below  all the editor templates from Kendo site or from [demo](http://www.telerik.com/clientsfiles/e77fd797-d279-47a1-a204-e9202df69396_TimePickerTests.zip?sfvrsn=0).

[image]

**Date.cshtml**

```
@model DateTime?

@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m))
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: For those who this didn't work for, my version of Kendo renders the input type as 'DateTime', thus naming the editor template 'DateTime.cshtml' worked.